# Android Fragment with buttons not shown on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm having an issue with a framgent displayed in the android studio designer but not when started at the device.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fcvNavHostId"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

navigation_graph.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/inOutListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/inOutListFragment"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.InOutListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_in_out_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_in_out_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_inOutListFragment_to_categoriesEditFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoriesEditFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_inOutListFragment_to_filtersFragment"
            app:destination="@id/filtersFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoriesEditFragment"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.CategoriesEditFragment"
        android:label="CategoriesEditFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesEditFragment_to_categoryEditFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryEditFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoryEditFragment"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.CategoryEditFragment"
        android:label="fragment_category_edit"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category_edit" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/filtersFragment"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.FiltersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_filters"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_filters" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_filtersFragment_to_filterFragment"
            app:destination="@id/filterFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/filterFragment"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.FilterFragment"
        android:label="fragment_filter"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_filter" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_filterFragment_to_filterStepFragment"
            app:destination="@id/filterStepFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/filterStepFragment"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.FilterStepFragment"
        android:label="fragment_filter_step"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_filter_step" />
</navigation>
```

fragment_inout_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".InOutListFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btCategories"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="showCategories"
            android:text="@string/categories" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFilters"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="showFilters"
            android:text="@string/filters" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fcvFilterTimeId"
        android:name="com.visrcrd.inout.TimespanFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_timespan" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fcvEditButtonsId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_buttons" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcvId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_time_span.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".TimespanFragment" >

    <com.visrcrd.inout.DateTextView
        android:id="@+id/dtBeginId"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <com.visrcrd.inout.TimeTextView
        android:id="@+id/dtBeginTimeId"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-" />

    <com.visrcrd.inout.DateTextView
        android:id="@+id/dtEndId"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <com.visrcrd.inout.TimeTextView
        android:id="@+id/dtEndTimeId"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_edit_buttons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btAddId"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_item"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/increase_volume" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btEditId"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/edit_item"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btDeleteId"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete_items"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyzfs.png)

[Screenshot from device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwmHF.jpg)

So you can see that the fragment fragment_edit_buttons.xml is not shown in the main page on the device but displayed in the designer. What is wrong with this design?

I tried to show the main page of the navigation graph and expected the fragment_edit_buttons fragment to be displayed on the device but it is missing.

Update:
Added EditButtonFragment.cs

...

```
package com.visrcrd.inout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link EditButtonsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class EditButtonsFragment extends Fragment {

    private InOutViewModel m_Model;

    public EditButtonsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment EditButtonsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static EditButtonsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EditButtonsFragment fragment = new EditButtonsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        }

        m_Model = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity(), new InOutViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication())).get(InOutViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_buttons, container, false);

        ImageButton btAdd = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btAddId);
        btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m_Model.getEditButtons().Add();
            }
        });

        ImageButton btEdit = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btEditId);
        btEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m_Model.getEditButtons().Update();
            }
        });

        ImageButton btDelete = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btDeleteId);
        btDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                m_Model.getEditButtons().Delete();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

...

Added InOutListFragment.cs:

...
package com.visrcrd.inout;

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.visrcrd.inout.databinding.FragmentInOutListBinding;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link InOutListFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class InOutListFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private InOutViewModel m_Model;

    private View m_View;

    private FragmentInOutListBinding m_Binding;

    public InOutListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment InOutListFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static InOutListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        InOutListFragment fragment = new InOutListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        m_Model = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity(), new InOutViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication())).get(InOutViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_in_out_list, container, false);

        m_Binding = FragmentInOutListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        View view = m_Binding.getRoot();
        m_View = view;

        return view;
    }

    public void showCategories(View view)
    {
        m_Model.showCategories();
    }

    public void showFilters(View view)
    {
        m_Model.showFilters();
    }

    public void Initialize(FragmentManager mgr)
    {
        FragmentContainerView fcv = (FragmentContainerView)m_View.findViewById(R.id.fcvFilterTimeId);
        TimespanFragment frag = (TimespanFragment)fcv.getFragment();
        frag.Initialize(mgr);
    }
}
```

...

MainActivity.cs:

```
package com.visrcrd.inout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.visrcrd.inout.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    InOutViewModel m_Model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        
        setContentView(view);

        m_Model = new ViewModelProvider(this, new InOutViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(InOutViewModel.class);
        m_Model.registerInOutListCallback(new InOutViewModel.IInOutFragmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowCategories() {
                NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(binding.fcvNavHostId);
                controller.navigate(R.id.action_inOutListFragment_to_categoriesEditFragment);
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowFilters() {
                NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(binding.fcvNavHostId);
                controller.navigate(R.id.action_inOutListFragment_to_filtersFragment);
            }
        });

        try {   
            m_Model.Initialize(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void showCategories(View view)
    {
        m_Model.showCategories();
    }

    public void showFilters(View view)
    {
        m_Model.showFilters();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        m_Model.setNavController(Navigation.findNavController(binding.fcvNavHostId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't adding string like `tools:context=".EditButtonsFragment"` in fragment_edit_buttons.xml solved your problem?

Comment: No, adding tools:context=".EditButtonsFragment" to the LinearLayout did not solve the problem.

Comment: Then, can you show code of EditButtonsFragment?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have added the code for EditButtonsFragment

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this class. Could you show some of the code when you set this fragment into a container?

Comment: The EditButtonFragment is used by InOutListFragment.cs / fragment_in_out_list.xml which  in turn is used by the navigation graph (navigation_graph.xml). I added the MainActivity.cs and InOutListFragment.cs.